# Text appear and move up while fading

Tags: javascript, html, css

i am wondering how i would make text pop u (in a div), where your mouse is and then fade away (like cookie clicker).

I would like to use Javascript.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?...

Comment: not really, i just dont know where to start... i tried with jquery here: inconspicuousstudios.com/2byte/strawberrygame

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My first piece of advice would be to open up the main.js cookie clicker file and poke around in there. Find the `Game.ClickCookie` method and find where he updates particles.

He uses a click event to create the particle. Every tick of game time (done using `setTimeout`) he updates any particles. In this case, he slides it up a little bit and decreases the transparency until it's invisible.

Depending on your situation, to get the mouse coordinates you could track the mouse coordinates at all times using a mousemove event (example in the cookie clicker code), or you can use the clientx and clienty attributes on the event parameter of your click handler.

```
myelement.onclick = function(event){
  var mousex = event.clientX;
  var mousey = event.clientY;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use **jQuery Custombox v1.1.3** its a simple plugin it'll do stuff for you.

```
//after download use this code
$('#example5').on('click', function ( e ) {    //can use any event
$.fn.custombox( this, {
    open: function () {
        //write close code with time mentioned.
    },

});
e.preventDefault();
});
```

you'll also have useful tutorials in their site...